# CoreService : AccessToken Issue while implementing Upload Binary using Coreservice

Tags: web8.5, core-service, binary

Trying to Build an API to upload Binary Using CoreService Web(8.5) in Java.
On using IStreamUpload.uploadBinary(AccessTokenData, byte[]), it gives exception Due to AccessToken. It gives the following Exception

> com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.IStreamUploadUploadBinaryByteArrayCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage: Provided access token is invalid.
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter.processFaultDetail(ClientFaultConverter.java:183)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ClientFaultConverter.handleMessage(ClientFaultConverter.java:83)
> at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112)
> at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:70)
> at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:35)
> at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:829)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1696)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1570)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
> at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
> at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:228)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
> at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
> at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
> at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.uploadBinaryByteArray(Unknown Source)

Since IStreamUpload does not have getCurrentUser method so, We are making two CXFClient proxies one for ICoreService and another for IStreamUpload and passing getCurrentUser from ICorseService.
Below is the code for client proxy creation.

```
public ICoreService getCXFClient(String url, String user, String pass) {

    String id = user + "/" + pass;
    if (mapCoreService != null && mapCoreService.get(id) == null) {
        coreServiceBaseUrl = url;
        String userNameLocal = user;
        String passwordLocal = pass;

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(ICoreService.class);
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(coreServiceBaseUrl
                + CORE_SERVICE_PATH + "/basicHttp");
        ICoreService lcCoreService = (ICoreService) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean
                .create();

        Client clientProxy = ClientProxy.getClient(lcCoreService);          
        LoggingInInterceptor lii = new LoggingInInterceptor();
        lii.setPrettyLogging(true);

        clientProxy.getInInterceptors().add(lii);

        LoggingOutInterceptor loi = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
        loi.setPrettyLogging(true);
        clientProxy.getOutInterceptors().add(loi);
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) clientProxy.getConduit();

        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy = httpConduit
                .getAuthorization();
        authorizationPolicy.setUserName(userNameLocal);
        authorizationPolicy.setPassword(passwordLocal);
        authorizationPolicy.setAuthorizationType("Basic");

        HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        policy.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
        policy.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
        policy.setAllowChunking(false);
        httpConduit.setClient(policy);

        mapCoreService.put(id, lcCoreService);

    }
    if (mapCoreService != null) {
        LOGGER.info("Core service ID user [{}] pass [{}] data [{}]", user,
                "############", mapCoreService.get(id));
        return mapCoreService.get(id);
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Core service ID user [{}] pass [{}] data [{}]", user,
                "############", "NULL");
    }

    return null;

}
Client clientProxy = null;

public UploadBinary getCXFUploadClient(String url, String user, String pass) {

    String id = user + "/" + pass;
    if (mapStreamUploadService != null && mapStreamUploadService.get(id) == null) {
        coreServiceBaseUrl = url;
        String userNameLocal = user;
        String passwordLocal = pass;

        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(UploadBinary.class);
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(coreServiceBaseUrl
                + CORE_SERVICE_PATH + "/streamUpload_basicHttp");
        /*QName qName = new QName(
                coreServiceBaseUrl
                + CORE_SERVICE_PATH + "/streamUpload_basicHttp");*/
        //jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setEndpointName(qName);
        UploadBinary lcCoreService = (UploadBinary) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean
                .create();
        
        Client clientProxy = ClientProxy.getClient(lcCoreService);

        LoggingInInterceptor lii = new LoggingInInterceptor();
        lii.setPrettyLogging(true);

        clientProxy.getInInterceptors().add(lii);

        LoggingOutInterceptor loi = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
        loi.setPrettyLogging(true);
        clientProxy.getOutInterceptors().add(loi);
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) clientProxy.getConduit();

        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy = httpConduit
                .getAuthorization();
        authorizationPolicy.setUserName(userNameLocal);
        authorizationPolicy.setPassword(passwordLocal);
        authorizationPolicy.setAuthorizationType("Basic");

        HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        policy.setConnectionTimeout(10000);
        policy.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
        policy.setAllowChunking(false);
        httpConduit.setClient(policy);

        mapStreamUploadService.put(id, lcCoreService);

    }
    if (mapStreamUploadService != null) {
        LOGGER.info("Core service ID user [{}] pass [{}] data [{}]", user,
                "############", mapStreamUploadService.get(id));
        return mapStreamUploadService.get(id);
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Core service ID user [{}] pass [{}] data [{}]", user,
                "############", "NULL");
    }

    return null;

}
```

Getting error in the below method at uploadBinaryByteArray

```
    private String uploadFile(File file,ICoreService clientlocal) {
    try {
        byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        dis.readFully(fileData);
        dis.close();
        IStreamUpload clientUpload = CoreServiceFactory.getInstance().getCXFUploadClient( "url","***", "***");
        String uploadFile = clientUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray(clientlocal.getCurrentUser(), fileData);
      return uploadFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("failed [{}]" ,Util.getStack(e));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What’s in the Tridion Event Log?

Comment: I think you might have to type cast this "clientlocal.getCurrentUser()" as AccessTokenData when passing into the method uploadBinaryByteArray()

Comment: The typecast doesnt help, still i am getting the same error.

Comment: ><CoreServiceFault xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Category>Security</Category><ErrorCode>AccessTokenInvalidSignature</ErrorCode><ExceptionName>InvalidAccessTokenException</ExceptionName><Messages><Message>Provided access token is invalid.</Message></Messages></CoreServiceFault

Answer (score 0):

If you're using old UDP stack it is possible that this is synchronization issue. Please try updating UDP and run it again

Comment: This is a CoreService question, it has nothing to do with UDP.